# How does #pragma simd reduction(<operator>:<variable>) work under the hood?

Tags: vectorization, intel, simd, avx

I would like to know in more detail how the simd reduction clause used by Intel compilers works under the hood.

In particular, for a loop of the form

```
double x = x_initial;
#pragma simd reduction(<operator1>:x)
for( int i = 0; i < N; i++ )
  x <operator2> some_value;
```

my naive guess is as follows: 
The compiler initializes a private copy of x for each vector lane, then iterates through the loop one vector width at a time.  If the vector width is 4 doubles, for example, this would correspond to N/4 iterations plus a peel loop at the end.  At each step of the iteration, each lane's private copy of x is updated using `operator2`, then at the end, the 4 vector lanes' private copies are combined using `operator1`.  The [auto-vectorization guide](https://software.intel.com/sites/default/files/8c/a9/CompilerAutovectorizationGuide.pdf) does not appear to address this directly.

I did some experimentation and found some results that agree with my expectation and some that don't.  For example, I tried the case

```
double x = 1;
#pragma simd reduction(*:x) assert
for( int i = 0; i < 16; i++ )
  x += a[i];  // All elements of a are equal to 3.0
cout << "x after (*:x), x += a[i] loop:  " << x << endl;
```

where `operator1` is * and `operator2` is +=.  When I compile for avx2, which has a vector width of 4 doubles, the output is 28561 = ( 1 + 4*a[i] )^4.  This implies that the code first initializes 4 lane-private copies of x to 1, then adds 3 to each of those copies 4 times as the 4-double-wide vector lane iterates across the trip count of 16.  Each lane-private copy of x is now equal to 13.  Finally, the lane-private copies are combined (reduced) using `operator2` which is *, yielding 13*13*13*13 = 28561.

However, when I switch the * and + operators, like so

```
x = 1;
#pragma simd reduction(+:x) assert
for( int i = 0; i < 16; i++ )
  x *= a[i];
cout << "x after (+:x), x *= a[i] loop:  " << x << endl;
```

and compile again for avx2, the output is 1.0.  If my theory were correct, each vector lane should end up containing a value of 1*3^4, which would then be combined using + to yield 4*3^4 = 324.  Evidently this is not the case.  What am I missing?

Comment: Why are you specifying one operator for the reduction, and then performing a reduction operation using a different operator? My understanding is that the`reduction` clause indicates to the compiler that the variables are "reduction variables", rather than private variables. The use case is then (using `+`):
`#pragma omp simd reduction(+:x)  [newline]
for(int i = 0; i < N; i++) { v = a[i]; /* Do something with v. */; x += v;}`

Comment: For the details as specified by the standard see section 2.15.3.6 (page 201) of the [OpenMP API Version 4.5 November 2015](http://www.openmp.org/wp-content/uploads/openmp-4.5.pdf).